# Ad Mob ads not showing regularly

Tags: android

I'm testing the ad mobs ads on a real device. Sometimes the ads shows up and sometimes it doesn't shows. I've no idea what the problem is.

While testing on a virtual device I used test ads and they always shows up but now I'am using real ads on a device with real app-id and unit-id.

Below is the code I'm using. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Java Code:

```
MobileAds.initialize(this,"ca-app-pub-8665656565286300~4683225285");
mAdview = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdview.loadAd(adRequest);
```

XML:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-8665656565286300/8888341401"
/>
```

Comment: when you created this ad id ? because sometimes it is taking more than 48 hours. Recently i have implemented it took around 3 days.

Comment: It's been 1-2 days since I created this ad

Comment: If it takes 3 days then why the ads are shown sometimes?

Comment: Can you answer me another question?